# Set sequential number on entries with specific condition

Tags: pandas

### Situation

I'm preparing the migration of user data and I have a list of user subscriptions, for which I try to give every user a member id.

We only want to migrate active subscriptions, which are identified with the value 1 in the row "active".  The oldest user should get the lowest number and count upwards from there.

### Problem

The oldest users already have renewed their subscription. Please have a look at this image:

[image]

If I order the dataset by date and set a sequential number from there, the oldest user doesn't get the lowest number since we only migrate active subscriptions. In the above image, the oldest user "one" should have the id 1 but gets the id 5 under my current setting.

### Possible Solution

I'm struggling to find a solution to solve this problem. I was thinking about finding a way to write:

- a) sort by date and set an ongoing member id
- b) check for each user mail adress with active = 1, if there is already an entry existing with active = 0 and if yes, overwrite the member id.

afterwards, it should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create sample dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"member_id":[1,2,3,4,5,6],
"active":[0,0,1,1,1,1],
"date": ["Jan 2020","Feb 2020","Mar 2020","Apr 2020","Jan 2021","Feb 2021"],
"mail": ["one@user.com","two@user.com","three@user.com","four@user.com","one@user.com","two@user.com"]})
```

Then find unique users and their ids:

```
# Change date column to datetime
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

# Sort rows by active and date columns
df = df.sort_values(by=["active","date"])

# Find unique users by order of appearance
users = df["mail"].unique()

# Find id of each user
users2id = {u:i+1 for i, u in enumerate(users)}

# Update id
df["member_id"] = df["mail"].apply(lambda u: users2id[u])
```